# Keycloak - Set static client secret

Tags: keycloak

I'm configuring keycloak authentication with a client with access-type confidential. Here, I have credentials with a client id and client secret.
 I was wondering if I can define a static client_secret, which does not change over time. So that it can be configured at boot, for example with docker.

Is this possible?

Comment: Would using curl be good enough?

Comment: @dreamcrash this is for getting the client_secret, not for defining a static client_secret.

Comment: So you want a way of getting the client_secret?

Comment: No. I want to set a static client_secret, that does not change over time.

Comment: What is your set up? the client_secret by default does not change over time unless you deploy keycloak from scratch

Comment: I think you miss understood me, you can with curl set the client secret as well not only get it

Comment: Já resolveste este problema?

Comment: No. Grep can set the client secret, ok. But it changes when i do some requests / logins on keycloak.

Comment: It should not change by default, unless you are recreating the client everything single time. Otherwise after the client is created the secret will remain the same

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since setting the secret is not possible this might help as workaround:

- Export client
- Set secret in file
- Delete existing client
- Import client

**Export Client**

Select your the client and choose "Export" in the "Action" menu:
[image]

**Set secret in file**

Open exported .json file and set your secret

[image]

**Delete existing client**

[image]

**Import client**

In the clients overview, import client
[image]

**Docker with predefined secret**

If you are using Docker it might make sense to prepare an exported realm with the according secret (be aware that the secret needs to be added manually after the export, for security reason keycloak does not export the secret).
Use the import mechanism to automatically import your realm: [Importing and Exporting Realms](https://www.keycloak.org/server/importExport#:%7E:text=To%20export%20a%20realm%2C%20you,started%20when%20invoking%20this%20command.&text=To%20export%20a%20realm%20to,%2D%2Ddir%20option.&text=When%20exporting%20realms%20to%20a,for%20each%20realm%20being%20exported)

```
bin/kc.[sh|bat] import --file <file>
```

or

```
bin/kc.[sh|bat] start --import-realm
```

> When you set the --import-realm option, the server is going to try to import any realm configuration file from the data/import directory. Each file in this directory should contain a single realm configuration. Only regular files using the .json extension are read from this directory, sub-directories are ignored.

Comment: You can set the client secret manually, with `curl`, or with `kcadm.sh`, at least. And it doesn't change over time anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can **generate** a static client secret in Keycloak after you create an *Access Type = confidential* client. You can do this in the Credentials tab for this client type. Note that the Credentials tab is not available or visible for public client types. For increased security, Keycloak does not allow the secret to be manually set through the UI. Once you generate the secret, it will remain fixed until it's regenerated again manually through the UI.

[image: Keycloak v16.10 - Generating a Client Secret]